# Issue with Hiding keyBoard when using Action sheet

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiactionsheet

I'm showing action sheet on `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, here is my code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // dept_label is my UITextField property
    if (textField == dept_label) {
        [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; // i also used dept_label instead textfield here...
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select"
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Manpower", @"Admin",@"Research" ,nil];
        [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleDefault];
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    }
}
```

Problem is the action sheet is get activated but keyboard is not getting hidden!

Comment: put `sleep(0.5);` stmt after `[textField resignFirstResponder];` :p

Comment: i dont think its matter of time because even after selecting values from action sheet , keyboard is still un-hided!

Comment: Have you tried it? Its Irrespective.. If keyboard is not hided previously. You cant expect keyboard to be hided after selecting UIActionSheet button.

Comment: yes i tried this, bt no change! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
finally this worked..

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField==dept_label){        
        [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Manpower", @"Admin",@"Research" ,nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];        

    }       
    return YES;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITextField` delegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == dept_label) {
        // dept_label is my UITextField property
        [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select"
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Manpower", @"Admin", @"Research", nil];
        [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleDefault];
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thnks omk, i tried this, but it restricts keyboard showing from all of my textfields as we returned NO, so i slightly modified your code and now its working :)